# #value error returns with excel user defined function

Tags: excel, vba

i have created user defined function to calculate football match results.

My Root Function looks that:

```
Function calculatePoints(personTypes As Range, matchesResults As Range) As Integer
    calculatePoints = getAllPersonPoints(personTypes, matchesResults)
End Function
```

getAllPersonPoints function:

```
Private Function getAllPersonPoints(personTypes As Range, matchesResults 
AsRange) As Integer
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim isTheSurest As Boolean
    getAllPersonPoints = 0

    For x = 1 To personTypes.Rows.Count
        For y = 1 To personTypes.Columns.Count
            isTheSurest = isTheSurestResult(personTypes.Cells(x, 
y).DisplayFormat.Interior.PatternColorIndex)
            getAllPersonPoints = getAllPersonPoints + 
getPoints(matchesResults.Cells(x, y).Value, personTypes.Cells(x, y).Value, 
isTheSurest)
        Next y
    Next x
End Function
```

When i am trying to call this function by setting manually parameters: personTypes range and matchesResults ragne - everythink works fine.

But when i am trying to call it from sheet i got #VALUE error in selected cell.

[image: #VALUE error at cell]

But at function form there is correct result:

[image: Correct value returned by function]

A have been trying to debug return value and always i got correct value. I have problem only with error in return cell.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why do you have a separate function `calculatePoints` that does nothing except call another function?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `DisplayFormat` object does not work with UDF's

See [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-displayformat-property-excel)

The usual solution to this is to evaluate the Conditional Format conditions to determine which one is active. For example, [see cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CFColors.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved problem by code:

```
personTypes.Cells(x, y).Interior.ColorIndex
```

instead of:

```
personTypes.Cells(x,y).DisplayFormat.Interior.PatternColorIndex
```

This solution works.

Comment: You realise that doesn't detect conditional format colors, right?